# PDFSharp or MigraDoc: How to create a multi-column page-layout?

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I want to use PDFSharp or MigraDoc to create PDFs with a multi-column pagelayout.
but I didnt find any hints how to do this?

The text should be placed on the page like in newspapers.

I cannot use tables, because tabels are organized by rows, but I only have a bulk of text, which should be filled in a three column page layout.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4):

MigraDoc does not support several columns on one page.

One workaround: set a smaller page size for the MigraDoc document (size of one column) and draw several of these "logical" MigraDoc pages on the columns of one physical PDFsharp.

See also:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx